# SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'xyz.com'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, https, socketexception

We launched our Flutter App on playstore yesterday and users are receiving this Socket exception while calling our backend APIs

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘xyz.com’ (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

The APIs work on some devices but failing on some. We are using https requests and the problem is **not** Android 10 specific. We have added internet permissions on all three AndroidManifest files so that is not the issue.

Also we are using gzip encoding in the request headers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which GCP product are you using? Please provide more details about your use case.

Comment: Some network operators were stopping our URLs which was causing the issue. Changing the URL solved the problem,

Comment: How did you change the URL? @user187293